# Http post successes with poster, but fails in python

Tags: python, http, github-api

In the code below, I'm trying to create a repository with http post, but I always get 400 bad request, when I send the http post with poster, I got 201 created, what's wrong with this code?

```
token = raw_input('Access Token: ')
url = 'https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=' + token
values = {"name":"newnewnewnew"}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read();
print the_page
```

Poster:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the GitHub API v3 documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#parameters), for `POST` request, the parameters should be encoded with **json** and the content-type should be `application/json`:

```
import json

....

token = raw_input('Access Token: ')
url = 'https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=' + token
values = {"name": "newnewnewnew"}
data = json.dumps(values)  # <---
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})  # <---
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```